# Not having a job when asking for a Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I would like to know if having a job is crucial when it comes to visa approval. I am not working at the moment, but my boyfriend will pay for all my expenses to travel to Italy one more time.

The first time I applied for the visa, I had a job and it was approved, but now I am concerned. I do have a good amount of money in the bank, and he will pay all my expenses. So is it ok if I don't have a job? Can how do I include that in the cover letter?

Answer (score 4):

Having a job to return to is helpful in demonstrating to a visa officer that you will return to your country at the end of your trip.

Nothing says that you MUST have a job in order to get a Schengen visa, but not having one makes it a bit harder to demonstrate that you will indeed return. Having a boyfriend in Italy only weakens your case, because it is an additional incentive for you to stay there.

Therefore, you need to demonstrate your intention to return to your home country another way. This can take many forms - for example, you may have dependent family members in your home country, may own immovable assets, or be involved in community activities. Your travel history should certainly work in your favour. If you are actively looking for a job in your home country, it could be helpful to mention that on your cover letter; otherwise, simply provide a clear explanation of your ties to your country, your reasons for undertaking this particular trip, a detailed itinerary, as well as return tickets. Beyond that, it will be the consulate's call to make.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the response . So even tho he is not Italian might weakened the decision? I put in my cover letter what I do which is work independently . Might this be enough ?

Comment: @María His citizenship doesn't matter. If he lives in Italy, it will weaken your case, as you will have an incentive to stay in Italy with him. However, if he lives in your home country, that is actually a strong tie to your home country for you, and you should mention it in your cover letter. If you are self-employed, it will help to provide some proof in your application. This could include a business license or corporate tax returns. If you are a freelancer, you can provide receipts for services you have rendered, as well as appropriate tax returns.